# TypeScript - Ajax Class implementing in TypeScript

Tags: ajax, typescript

I am trying to write Ajax Class using TypeScript. TypeScript code –

```
class Ajax {
    url: string;
    xmlData: string;
    mode: bool; 
    response: string;
    objHttpReq:any;

    constructor (postUrl: string, postXml: string, postMode: bool) {
        this.url = postUrl;
        this.xmlData = postXml;
        this.mode = postMode;       
        this.objHttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
        this.objHttpReq.mode = this.mode;   

        this.objHttpReq.onreadystatechange = this.OnRStateChange;

        this.objHttpReq.open("Post", this.url, this.mode);
        this.objHttpReq.send(this.xmlData);         
    }                   

    OnRStateChange(){               
        if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200)
                    //here this refers to Ajax
        {
            //alert(xmlhttp.status);
            if( this.mode == false)
            {
                alert(this.responseText);
            }
            else
            {
                alert(this.responseText);
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Complied JavaScript of above code

```
var Ajax = (function () { 

    function Ajax(postUrl, postXml, postMode) {
        this.url = postUrl;
        this.xmlData = postXml;
        this.mode = postMode;
        this.objHttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
        this.objHttpReq.mode = this.mode;
        this.objHttpReq.onreadystatechange = this.OnRStateChange;
        this.objHttpReq.open("Post", this.url, this.mode);
        this.objHttpReq.send(this.xmlData);
    }
    Ajax.prototype.OnRStateChange = function () {
        if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
         //here this refers XMLHttpRequest object – works fine
            if(this.mode == false) {
                alert(this.responseText);
            } else {
                alert(this.responseText);
            }
        }
    };
    return Ajax;
})();
```

Issue is above TypeScript code is showing error because Ajax class does not have readyState, status and responseText properties. What should be the correct code for writing Ajax Class in TypeScript?

Comment: Did you figure this out ?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add the appropriate properties like this:

```
class Ajax {
    url: string;
    xmlData: string;
    mode: bool; 
    response: string;
    objHttpReq:any;
    readyState: number;
    status: number;
    responseText: string;

    constructor (postUrl: string, postXml: string, postMode: bool) {
        this.url = postUrl;
        this.xmlData = postXml;
        this.mode = postMode;       
        this.objHttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
        this.objHttpReq.mode = this.mode;   

        this.objHttpReq.onreadystatechange = this.OnRStateChange;

        this.objHttpReq.open("Post", this.url, this.mode);
        this.objHttpReq.send(this.xmlData);         
    }                   

    OnRStateChange(){               
        if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200)
                    //here this refers to Ajax
        {
            //alert(xmlhttp.status);
            if( this.mode == false)
            {
                alert(this.responseText);
            }
            else
            {
                alert(this.responseText);
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Steve for your response, but don't you think object of Ajax class never use readyState, status or responseText properties. May be you are correct but i am not 100% satisfied with the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I propose to amend your class a bit:

In the constructor you can adjust as follows:

```
this.objHttpReq.onreadystatechange = () => this.OnRStateChange();
```

And thereafter in the function OnRStateChange you can refer to

```
this.objHttpReq.readyState;
this.objHttpReq.status;
this.objHttpReq.responseText;
```

So finally your class will look as follows:

```
class Ajax {
    url: string;
    xmlData: string;
    mode: bool; 
    response: string;
    objHttpReq:any;

    constructor (postUrl: string, postXml: string, postMode: bool) {
        this.url = postUrl;
        this.xmlData = postXml;
        this.mode = postMode;       
        this.objHttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
        this.objHttpReq.mode = this.mode;   

        this.objHttpReq.onreadystatechange =()=> this.OnRStateChange();

        this.objHttpReq.open("Post", this.url, this.mode);
        this.objHttpReq.send(this.xmlData);         
    }                   

    OnRStateChange(){               
        if (this.objHttpReq.readyState==4 && this.objHttpReq.status==200)
                    //here this refers to Ajax
        {
            //alert(xmlhttp.status);
            if( this.objHttpReq.mode == false)
            {
                alert(this.objHttpReq.responseText);
            }
            else
            {
                alert(this.objHttpReq.responseText);
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Kind Regards
E